# Can you identify this font used for the text Bonbons?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Would anyone know the name of the typeface used for "Bonbons" and if possible the typeface used for the text above and below it? Online font identifiers like come close, but do not provide an exact match. https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont suggested `ITC Edwardian Script Std Bold` and many others that are not exact.

[image]

Comment: If you can't find a font through WhatTheFont's automated engine, you can submit your image to the forum and get lots of help there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: [The other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/150849/18168) is more accurate and has more details.

---

The Bonbons font looks like from **ITC Edwardian Script** family. But like you said, it is a bit different. **B** looks different a bit.

[image]

I found same on a website (not sure if it's legal or not) named `blogfonts.com`, but that matched a great deal:

[image]

So I feel it could be an old version of font which is not available now. More details about this family are here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/edwardian-script-itc

---

The second font (*Maison Fondee* text) is not so easy to find unless there's a better quality reference image. **Vollkorn SC** is a similar typeface that I found in Google fonts:

[image]

Another similar I found on `fonts.com` is [LTC Cloister Small Caps](https://www.fonts.com/font/p22-type-foundry/ltc-cloister/small-caps)

[image]

(I'm not sure about the font used for digits next to *Maison Fondee* text)

Comment: Your first image is the reason I asked here. Notice the "B"?

Comment: @jmenezes yes. That is probably the latest font version. See second image. Do you think second image matches?

Comment: The second image is a perfect match. Any idea what the font used for the text above and below Bonbons might be?

Comment: @jmenezes yes I have some idea :D but I didn't mention it because I'm not sure if that website is legal or not. I'm sharing it here. Explore it at your own risk: https://blogfonts.com/edwardian-script-itc.font

Comment: @jmenezes I just found a disclaimer. If you will go to the footer of website, there's a disclaimer. Please read before you proceed.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, are you identifythisfont subreddit?

Comment: No. Not really.

Comment: Ok. I meant to ask "are you "on" the identifythisfont subreddit?" I missed the "on" in my previous post.

Comment: @jmenezes no. I'm very new to Reddit and not very active. Why btw? It looks useful subreddit. Since Reddit works in a very different way, the rules are a bit easy there I guess.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is Edwardian Script but the capital B is an [alternate character](https://www.typography.com/faq/157). The [Pro version you can buy on MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/edwardian-script/) includes it in a stylistic set if you look through the [character set](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/edwardian-script?tab=glyphs).

The inline font is a French typeface called "Le Moreau-le-Jeune". It's often been branded, not accurately, as "Caslon Openface" in English-speaking countries. This version is Letraset's [Academy Engraved](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/academy-engraved/) and has a higher x-height than most digital versions.

Comment: Oops. I missed this thing. Good job.

Comment: I tried to find the smaller font a lot but failed.

Comment: @Vikas I think the smaller font is [Academy Engraved](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/academy-engraved/).

Comment: @MarkRansom nice :D I vaguely had a thought that the font has two lines instead of single stroke. I have edited my question. I want to apologize as I made a mistake. I'm very sure the font you suggested is almost match and a lot of chances that it is actually the font being used. You might want to add that as an answer :)

Comment: @Vikas I didn't consider leaving an answer because I didn't notice the question was asking about all three lines!  The top line is different from the other two and I don't have an answer for that.  I'm sure I've seen that "M" before but can't remember.

Comment: @MarkRansom oh. It looks like a bit like Trajan Pro but digits don't match.

Comment: The inline font is a French typeface called "Le Moreau-le-Jeune". It's often been branded (wrongly) as "Caslon Openface" in English-speaking countries. This version has a higher x-height than most.